# What type of FunctionN instance is created when creating anonymous function with no parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, scala-2.12

I wrote the below scala code in my IDE(IntelliJ) to create an anonymous function :

```
val hi = () => "Hi"
```

When I desugar my scala code , IDE gives me code like one below :

```
val hi: Function1[(), _root_.java.lang.String] = () => "Hi"
```

But it is giving error : `'=>' expected but ',' found.`

1. I am keen to know the Function type of the anonymous function.
2. I also want to know why the IDE is giving me this result which is actually throwing error.

Comment: Not sure what is your first question, and the answer to your second question is that the IDE has a bug. BTW, the desugaring is wrong also.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I apologize if my first question is unclear. I know that it is an instance of Function1, lets say it has a signature of Function1[? , String] , what is '?' here ? I would really appreciate if you can mention any term that I have used incorrectly so that it could help me fix the question I have asked.

Comment: `hi` is not a `Function1` is a `Function0`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function0.html

Answer (score 1):

As said by Luis, `hi` is a function of no input parameter that produces a `String`, thus its type is `Function0[String]`.

If it was defined like this for instance it would be a `Function1[String, String]`:

```scala
val hi1 = (name: String) => s"Hi $name"
```